# Made2Manage ERP Web service method information

Tags: m2m

I am using Mane2Manage ERP Web service but want to know about methods.
Which method I can use to getting Customer and Sales Order.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP GET
Use GET requests to retrieve resource representation/information only – and not to modify it in any way. As GET requests do not change the state of the resource, these are said to be safe methods. Additionally, GET APIs should be idempotent, which means that making multiple identical requests must produce the same result every time until another API (POST or PUT) has changed the state of the resource on the server.